# How to exclude light from a character

Tags: rendering, light, lighting, shadows, emission

I'm working on a scene where a character is floating inside a cylinder and there's light shining from the bottom. To make it appealing I had to turn the strength to 10000. But my mixamo character can't be seen. The textures aren't visible. I found out that if I turn bloom off it works but it affects the cylinder. Is there a way to enable light to touch the cylinder but not a character. I'm trying for a silhouette style where the characters appear black at the center of the light

Comment: I guess you need to use the Compositor. You could also give your character an Emission shader if it works for you

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a better answer, maybe using render layers, but I don't know it. It sounds like you can use a low poly proxy of your character though, for that scene and have the proxy be flat-black, where there will be no reflections. I know this is more a workaround but it may work for you. Otherwise I would play with render layers and the way the light effects that layer.